# Rails Devise current_admin nil when passing headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, devise, token

i am currently developing an API with rails api, i'm having some issue with multiple devise user models. I am also utilizing simple_token_authentication
gem to help generating a token for authentication.

So currently i've created this 2 user model for devise.
**User** and
**Admin**

my controllers for this 2 devise model is very identical,  this is my database attributes for both user&admin devise, basically my destroy method will reset my token_authentication from my database.

```
=> ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "authentication_token"]
```

This is a admin account sample entry in database

```
=> <Admin id: 1, email: "admin@gmail.com", created_at: "2017-07-19 15:05:49", updated_at: "2017-07-19 15:05:49", authentication_token: "UAUK6JngFVbRr5QYeeFo">
```

My problem is now, i keep getting Error with my DELETE #destroy method on my admin controller, but my user controller destroy method is working fine.

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"#\u003cNoMethodError: undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass\u003e","traces":{"Application Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"app/controllers/v1/adminsessions_controller.rb:20:in `destroy'"}],"Framework Trace":[{"id":1,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'"},{"id":2,"trace":"actionpack (5.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'"},
```

Here is both of how my controller looks like

Admin sessions Controller

```
class V1::AdminsessionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    current_admin ? head(:ok) : head(:unauthorized)
  end

  def create
    @admin = Admin.where(email: params[:email]).first

    if @admin&.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render :create, status: :created
    else
      render json: {
        message: "Wrong password or email"
      }.to_json, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_admin&.authentication_token = nil
    if current_admin.save
      head(:ok)
    else
      head(:unauthorized)
    end
  end
end
```

User Sessions Controller

```
    class V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    current_user ? head(:ok) : head(:unauthorized)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first

    if @user&.valid_password?(params[:password])
      render :create, status: :created
    else
      render json: {
        message: "Wrong password or email"
      }.to_json, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user&.authentication_token = nil
    if current_user.save
      head(:ok)
    else
      head(:unauthorized)
    end
  end


end
```

it kept saying undefined method `save' so i went and byebug, i realize current_admin is nil, i can't figure out why it is always nil. i've passed the token and email in the headers. Please help guys. thanks!

Comment: The Admin seems to not be signed in. Did you follow the step described in Devise's doc? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models

Comment: i follow this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models